# 9 ноября — открытие конференции. Подлежащее и сказуемое

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> 9 ноября — открытие конференции.

Где здесь подлежащее и сказуемое? Можно ли считать эту конструкцию предложением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Всё зависит от того, как мы определяем предложение.** Очень долгое время (от Аристотеля до середины XIX века) предложение соотносилось с логическим суждением (предмет и суждение о нем). Дальше следовал долгий период развития грамматической науки, и теперь под предложением может пониматься соотнесенность друг с другом двух понятий, представлений, а также предметов, признаков, явлений и т.д.

В основе современного синтаксиса лежат **два понятия:** предложение как грамматическая форма  и предложение как сематическое высказывание.

Грамматическая форма предполагает наличие предикативности (время и модальность), а высказывание должно строиться по принципу коммуникативности, то есть его содержание должно быть понятным для слушателя.

***9 ноября — открытие конференции.***

Нам понятно это содержание? Да, вполне: названа дата, когда откроется конференция.

А теперь рассмотрим его **грамматику.**

Предложение нужно видеть в контексте, например: *Девятого  ноября — открытие конференции. К этому времени еще многое надо сделать.*

Это **двусоставное предложение эллиптического типа,** вполне известная структура (обстоятельство —  подлежащее, сказуемое подразумевается, но не называется).

**А если это перечень: дата —  событие?** Коммуникативность тоже вполне понятная, но грамматика уже другая. Предложение построено по принципу координации двух предметов (в форме И.п.).

Структурная схема строится по принципу сущ. в И.п. — сущ. в И.п.. Лексико-семантическое наполнение компонентов —  свободное. Позиция существительного может быть занята именным сочетанием (материал из Грамматики-80).

В нашем случае позицию первого сущ. занимает дата (именное сочетание)

**Примечание.** Предложение нельзя считать неполным, у него вполне определенная структура.

Comment: Знаю, что писать просто благодарственный комментарий нежелательно, но напишу. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, привести более точную ссылку на место в источнике

Answer (score 0):

Это неполное предложение с пропуском связки сказуемого или сказуемого. Исходя из контекста, это - было (будет) открытие, состоится (состоялось, запланировано, произойдет) открытие.